# What assumptions can we safely make about the Java Collections shuffle(List<?>, Random) method?

Tags: java, shuffle

So I am looking into the collections shuffle method and trying to come up with a list of what is and is not ensured when we run it. There are some obvious cases I've come up which are the following:

1. The list given will contain the same elements after shuffling as before
2. The list may or may not be the same after running the method (you could end up with the same order of elements)
3. The method will run in linear time (I think that this is true but am not 100% positive).

Does this list sum it up or am I missing some possible cases?

Comment: I'd say 1. The list may or may not be the same, 2. the method will run in linear time, and 3. the list will contain the same elements as before

Comment: @JustinL. So even if the list does not implement RandomAccess and is large we get a linear running time? Good to know.

Comment: It was actually a joke about list shuffling, I don't actually know anything about the method :o

Comment: What overload are you looking at that takes an int?

Comment: @user2357112 Ah that was my mistake. I meant to put Random there. Good catch

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [official documentation of `Collections.shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) has a lot to say about what will happen. The list will be shuffled using what seems to be the [Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), which (assuming that random access is available in O(1)) runs in time O(n) and space O(1). The implementation will use space O(n) if random access isn't available. Assuming that the underlying random source is totally unbiased, the probability of any particular ordering occurring is equal (that is, you get a uniformly-random distribution over possible permutations).

So, to answer your questions:

1. The list will contain the same elements.
2. They're probably in a different order, but there's a 1 / n! chance than they'll be in the same order.
3. The runtime is O(n), and the space usage is either O(1) or O(n) depending on whether your list has random access support.

Comment: To be pedantic, the distribution can only be pseudo-uniform if the number of states of the PRNG is << n!. Otherwise, some of the n! permutations will never be reached.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes (and more over- the list itself will remain the same object)
2. correct, there's always the slight chance of randomly getting the exact same order of elements (not that slight for small lists)
3. this is implementation based, but at least till java 7 it is linear (and not probable reason for it to change)